# how to make a password constant?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, authentication, passwords

I'm Developing an Android app in which there is a Login activity and a Questionnaire activity. So now I wanted to make the user to access the app only by entering the unique id which will help in blocking unauthorized users. I tried with the code but when i press the login button it pops the alert dialogue even if the password is matching the password I've given. And the password i wanted to keep is 'VISTEON'. If the password entered is rite then it should intent to the next activity.

check my java code and help me to modify it.

[image: this is my Login activity]

Here is my java code

```
public class Klogin extends Activity {
EditText editText1;
Button login;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_login);
    addButtonListener();
}
public void addButtonListener()
{
    Button login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            if(validationSuccess()){
                 Intent intent = new Intent(Klogin.this, Login.class);
                 startActivity(intent);
             }
         }
     });
    
     
    }

private Boolean validationSuccess()
{
    EditText visteon = null;
    if(editText1==visteon)
    {
        alertDialog();
        return false;
    }
    
     return true;
 }
 private void alertDialog()
 {
     AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Klogin.this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Please ENTER the Correct password").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
                    {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

            AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alert.show();

 }
```

Comment: 1) You haven't initialized `editText1`. 2) Use `getText()` to get the text from `EditText`. 3) Do you know how to compare `String` in Java?

Comment: Sorry I don't know. I'm just a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
public void addButtonListener()
{
     Button login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
     editText1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
     login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            if(validationSuccess(editText1.getText().toString().trim())){
                 Intent intent = new Intent(Klogin.this, Login.class);
                 startActivity(intent);
             }
         }
     });
}
```

and

```
private Boolean validationSuccess(String value)
{
    if(!value.equals("VISTEON"))
    {
        alertDialog();
        return false;
    }

     return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this way first initialized `EditText edit_password` like

```
 EditText edit_password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_password);
```

Now, create `validationSuccess(......)` like

```
private Boolean validationSuccess(String str)
{ 

if(!str.equals("yourcorrectpassword"))
{
    alertDialog();
    return false;
}

 return true;
}
```

Now called this function like

```
login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        if(validationSuccess(edit_password.getText.toString())){
             Intent intent = new Intent(Klogin.this, Login.class);
             startActivity(intent);
         }
     }
 });
```

And make sure you have `EditText` with id `edit_password` in your `activity_main_login.xml` layout file.

Answer (score 0):

For start you are not setting the `visteon` variable.  This only needs to be a String.

Then when you user enters the value, you need to get the String from the `editText1` and then check using `equals` as to whether it is correct or not.  The `==` operator will check for equality of objects, not their values.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `if(editText1.getText().toString().equals("VISTEON"))`.